# jquery enclose current element in a new parent container

Tags: jquery, new-operator, parent

I want to enclose using jquery around the current element a new parent container, something like that, but I don't like the following lines and I suppose that they are not really correct or best practice:

```
this.before('<div id="container">');
this.after('</div>');
// do something with the new parent here
$("#container")...
```

Is there a way more natural of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use the wrap function that is built for this!

```
this.wrap('<div id="container"></div>');
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: This works nicely, but can you (or someone else) explain why the approach described by m.john does not work as expected?

Comment: Moreover, how can I get a wrapping object? I thought that maybe wrap(...) would return it, but that is not the case...Do I have to search for it using siblings/children or is there a neat way?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on the details on why m.john's approach does not work. My guess is that when jQuery functions take HTML, they try to make it into real elements, such that when the call to before with the partial div is made it makes it into a real div, placing the whole thing before the target in question.

Comment: On the other hand, to get the reference to the new wrapper, you can call `this.wrap('<div id="containter"></div>').parent()` and you will get the new wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/rPhF2/

Instead of `<div/>` you can also use e.g. `<div id="container"/>`